# (1, 1) weak inequality for Hardy's integral operator

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Consider Hardy's integral operator $T$ defined on $L^1(0, +\infty)$ by
$$ Tf(x) = \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t) \, dt, \quad x \in (0, +\infty), f \in L^1(0, +\infty).$$
I need to find a constant $C > 0$ such that
$$ \lambda m(|Tf| > \lambda) \leq C{\Vert f \Vert}_1 \quad \text{for all } \, \lambda > 0, f \in L^1(0, +\infty)$$
where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

I don't know how to tackle this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $f_0:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R $ be the extension of $f$ by zero. $$|Tf(x)| \le \frac1x\int_0^x |f(x)| dx\le Mf_0(x) := \sup_{I\ni x}\frac1{|I|} \int_I |f_0(x)|dx$$
Since the Hardy-Littlewood maximal operator $M$ is weak $(1,1)$,
$$ m( |Tf|\ge \lambda ) \le m(Mf_0\ge \lambda) \le \frac C \lambda  \|f_0\|_{L^1(\mathbb R)} = \frac C \lambda  \|f\|_{L^1((0,\infty))}. $$